# Can this scheme be circumvented?

Tags: custom-scheme

I am currently developing software, in which players essentially make a "bet".

While not exactly congruent to my situation, I will use the example of a randomly shuffled 52 card deck, in which the player is revealed the top card and has to bet whether the next card is higher, lower or identical in value. In the real world, players see me shuffling the deck and that I am no longer touching it after handing them their card. They can see that the next card is pre-determined by how the deck was initially shuffled and that I cannot influence the deck as it is.

However, because this is handled by a server, I could technically manipulate the result before being presented to the player. The player could therefore believe that the server is cheating. As a result, I have to ensure two things:

- Players need to be able to verify, that the system is not scamming them.
- Players must not be able to calculate the result before making their bet; only afterwards.

In order to do so, I came up with the following scheme:

1. First, the server generates a 512-bit nonce `N` .
2. Next, the server shuffles the deck and serializes it some way (e.g. (`4♠,2♣,K♥`...). This serialized deck will be called `D`
3. The server takes the nonce and appends the serialized deck to it, then hashes this using SHA-512. So `H = SHA512(N+D)`
4. Both `H`and `N` are presented to the player, as well as the first card in the deck.
5. The player then makes their bet.
6. Afterwards, the rest of the deck is revealed to the player and it is determined whether they won or lost.
7. The player can now verify that the deck has existed *in this state* before their bet was made.

In a 52 card deck, the number of possible permutations is 52!, which is 225 bits of security. Attempting to calculate the deck solely based on the hash should be infeasible. Further, keep in mind that this is just an example. The software I am developing has roughly 2<sup>23 000</sup> different possible states, which should make brute forcing impossible, but verification simple. Further, even if someone were to be able to pre-compute *some* states, the random nonce would make that impossible.

Are there any issues with this scheme, specifically regarding the two requirements I mentioned?

Comment: would it be useful to assume a larger deck than 52 cards so that the number of permutations works, or is the deck of cards a bad example?

Comment: @Jasen The whole card analogy is just ab example for illustration purposes. Although 52! is a very large search space.

Answer (score 6):

This is roughly what's called a *commitment scheme*.  You perform some operation and commit to its value, and then you reveal it later.

What I would do here is use HMAC-SHA512 with `N` as the key instead of concatenating the two values, and only provide `H` as the commitment, instead revealing `N` and `D` at the end.  That's because in general, using HMAC with secrets is a better design than concatenating with a hash, and because in a standard commitment scheme using HMAC, the key is not revealed until the end.  Using a more common design helps people have confidence in your approach, but in this particular case, I don't see an obvious flaw in your design as it stands.

This doesn't necessarily mean that the server can't cheat here, because if we know, say, that usually 60% of the time humans will guess their card is higher, the server can always shuffle the deck to give it an advantage.  If you want to avoid that, the server can commit to a random 512-bit seed instead of the deck, then the clients can also commit to random seeds in the same way, the clients can reveal their seeds, and then all of the random seeds (client and server) in a fixed order can be used to seed a CSPRNG to shuffle the deck.  At the end, the server can reveal their seed, and all parties can verify the deck.  Since all of the parties need to contribute random seeds here and everybody has committed to their seeds beforehand, it makes it impossible for any one party to illegitimately influence the result based on someone else's seed.

Comment: I presume the security from using a HMAC stems from the fact that when calculating h = hmac(d, k), it is not possible to efficiently calculate hmac(d', k'), which generates the same h, right?

Comment: Correct, if you use a secure hash function.  Note that using something with collisions like [MD5 is trivially insecure in the case of a commitment scheme](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25584/is-hmac-md5-still-secure-for-commitment-or-other-common-uses).

Comment: Thank you a lot. HMAC-SHA256 should be fine if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Yup, HMAC with any SHA-2, SHA-3, or BLAKE2 algorithm should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any *theoretical* weaknesses. The number of states is high and cannot be brute-forced. Any pre-calculations make no sense because each state uses a new nonce.

The word *salt* would be better than *nonce* in this context, because despite technically they are similar, the purpose of nonce is to prevent replay attacks.

There might be weaknesses in the implementation, e.g. if RNG is not good enough or if the card deck is implemented incorrectly. This might lead to the fact that some combinations are more probable than the others. You would need good statistical tests.